I get an error when I try to "npx expo start -c"
error: .plugins is not a valid Plugin property when setting up Tailwind CSS with 
React Native and NativeWind

I'm trying to set up Tailwind CSS in my React Native project using NativeWind, but I'm encountering the following error when I run the app:
error: node_modules/expo-router/entry.js: \[BABEL\] ............/node_modules/expo-router/entry.js: .plugins is not a valid Plugin property

What I've Done:

Installed nativewind and tailwindcss.
Configured babel.config.js and tailwind.config.js according to the NativeWind documentation.
Tried rolling back the Tailwind CSS version.
Attempted to adjust the Babel configuration.

Files:
babel.config.js:
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['nativewind/babel', 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};

tailwind.config.js:`
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './client/screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './client/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  presets: [require('nativewind')],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

package.json dependencies:
"dependencies": {
  "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
  "axios": "^1.7.7",
  "cheerio": "^1.0.0",
  "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
  "expo": "~51.0.28",
  "expo-constants": "^16.0.2",
  "expo-linking": "^6.3.1",
  "expo-location": "^17.0.1",
  "expo-router": "^3.5.23",
  "expo-status-bar": "^1.12.1",
  "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
  "install": "^0.13.0",
  "moment": "^2.30.1",
  "mongoose": "^8.7.2",
  "mysql": "^2.18.1",
  "nativewind": "^4.1.20",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.74.5",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.20.0",
  "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.11.1",
  "react-native-screens": "^3.34.0",
  "tailwindcss": "3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.25.9",
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.9"
},
"resolutions": {
  "react-native-reanimated": "3.10.1"
},

app.d.ts:
/// <reference types="nativewind/types" />

Aditional Information:
I'm using Expo SDK version ~51.0.28.
I've made sure that react-native-reanimated is properly configured and that its Babel plugin is listed last in the plugins array.
I've tried clearing caches and reinstalling node_modules.
What could be causing the .plugins is not a valid Plugin property error in my setup? How can I fix this so that I can use Tailwind CSS with React Native and NativeWind?

https://github.com/nativewind/nativewind/issues/841#issuecomment-2006757850

i found my Problem. in case anyone has the same Problem.
in babel.config.js
nativewind/babel belongs in the presets: []
not in plugins: []

module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', 'nativewind/babel'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};

Try the above once
